# How to close a dialogfragment after rotating the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have implemented a dialogFragment which shows a simple message:

```
private static DialogFragment loadingDialogFragment = null;

public void showLoadingDialog(String title, String message) {
    loadingDialogFragment = new LoadingDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    args.putString("message", message);
    loadingDialogFragment.setArguments(args);
    loadingDialogFragment.show(fragManager, "loadingDialog");
}

public void dismissLoadingDialog() {
    if (loadingDialogFragment != null) {
        loadingDialogFragment.dismiss();
    }
}
```

However if the dialogue is shown and I rotate the screen, then my dissmisslaodingDialog doesn't work. I am thinking this is because when you rotate it calls the on create function again and it loosing the reference to the dialog, but i have made it static.

The code above is put in a Utility class which I call from my activity like so:

```
util.showLoadingDialog("Loading", "");
SendCommand(deviceId, "Command");
```

I then call `utils.dismissLoadingDialog` in the callback function of the SendCommmand.

What am I missing here?

{EDIT}

The code in my activityFragment

```
util.showLoadingDialog("Loading", "");
SendCommand(deviceId, "Command");

public void SendCommand(int deviceId, final String command) {

        Network.get(mContext, "/" + command + "/" + deviceId, null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.i(TAG + " sendPanelCommand", "recieved ok response to command: " + command);                
                util.dismissLoadingDialog();
            }

             @Override
             public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                util.dismissLoadingDialog();                    
                util.showErrorDialog(
                        "Error",
                        "An error has occored while trying to issue the command to the panel. This can be caused by network issues or your panel sending out priority information such as alarms. Please try again.");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Utils Class:

```
public class Utils {

private Context context;
private FragmentManager fragManager;

public Utils(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Utils(Context context, FragmentManager fragman) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fragManager = fragman;
}
...

private DialogFragment loadingDialogFragment = null;

public void showLoadingDialog(String title, String message) {
    loadingDialogFragment = new LoadingDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    args.putString("message", message);
    loadingDialogFragment.setArguments(args);
    loadingDialogFragment.show(fragManager, "loadingDialog");
}

public void dismissLoadingDialog() {
    if (loadingDialogFragment != null) {
        loadingDialogFragment.dismiss();
    } else {
        // the reference is null, try the FragmentManager to see if it
        // wasn't
        // automatically restored
        DialogFragment dg = (DialogFragment) fragManager.findFragmentByTag("loadingDialog");
        if (dg != null) {
            // this reference isn't null so the dialog is available
            dg.dismiss();
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: You're right, you lose the reference to the dialog. In the `dismissLoadingDialog()` method, first check the `loadingDialogFragment` reference for being `null`, if it's null then try to initialize it through the `FragmentManager`(by searching for a fragment with the tag `loadingDialog`), only after this steps try to dismiss it. **Don't** make the reference static

Comment: Could you possibly provide an example using the fragment manger. I don't currently use it to instantiate the dialogfragment,

Comment: @Zapnologica your accpetance ratio is very less.you are not acceping your previous answer..if this happens no one will answer for your questons..try to improve it..

Comment: @kalyanpvs I will only accept answers that actually address or answer the question correctly otherwise I think it defeats the point of SO. If its marked as the answer, then one would expect it to answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

Cancel a `DialogFragment` on screen rotation.  What I found out a few minutes ago after searching and trying all the variations for dismissing and handling rotation was the `onPause` method of the `DialogFragment` gets called during the rotation and you can dismiss it there.

```
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    // Global field to contain the error dialog
    private Dialog mDialog;

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        this.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    static ErrorDialogFragment newInstance() {
        ErrorDialogFragment d = new ErrorDialogFragment();
        return d;
    }
 ...
}
```

Comment: It's an auto dismissing on rotation dialog that I have in a utility class.

Answer (score 6):

To restrict dialog recreation you can override onCreate method in your dialog:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) dismiss();
}
```